# Percorrer valor especifico em Array PHP

Tags: php, array

Tenho uma conexão via api com um sistema de terceiros, estou recebendo os valores neste formato:

```
Array ( [code] => 200 [data] => Array ( [subscription_id] => 2752 [status] => new [custom_id] => [charges] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [charge_id] => 97652 [status] => new [total] => 1990 [parcel] => 1 ) ) [created_at] => 2016-08-29 20:17:12 ) )
```

O que preciso é pegar o valor de `charge_id`, acho que é simples, mas, não encontrei a maneira exata de achá-lo.

Comment: Tenta   echo $data['data']['charges'][0]['charge_id']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creio que você pode usar um foreach dessa forma:

```
foreach($data['data']['carges'] as $key => $value)
{
    echo $value['charge_id'];
}
```